# Can we read 4th byte from hexadecimal value?

Tags: java, byte, bit-manipulation, hex

Actually I am not so clear about it so I put a question here, and I am also new to bit calculation. My scenario is like this, I get some hexadecimal value from `CAN` (A hardware device) , for one perticular value I have to read 4th byte , in this 4th byte the value of bit 5 and 6 decides the output to be written, I mean if 5 & 6 th bit is 00= off , 01= on like this. So my question is , how can we read 4th or any particular byte and in byte particular bits from a hexadecimal. If possible please  give me some guidance or examples  or any tutorial sites. I googled a lot but no use . Please help me in this. and I want this to be done in java.

Comment: what is the input data type ?

Comment: Can you give a few examples of the value coming in?

Comment: @JigarJoshi input datatype is hexadecimal

Comment: but in what java data type ? (String ? int ? what exactly )

Comment: and example input and output ? (just to make sure)

Comment: @Prashant 18FE4A03 it gives me Engine Crank Enable , I have to read Byte 2 , bit 6,5 and 00=Crank disable, 01= Crank enable

Comment: @Raghu Did you try using a BitSet?

Comment: @VishalP No I dont know abt that.

Comment: Do you really care about all 8 bits of the byte, or just the 5th and 6th bits?

Comment: @user949300 I care about all 8 bits but for this question i just put 5, 6th bit. If u have some other solution please post it . it really helps me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that the value is 32 bit.

```
for example assume the input is 0x4FAEBCDB
```

I am assuming you want to extract the 4 byte which is DB.

Doing the AND operation with 0x000000FF will extract just the 4th byte.

```
That is 
0x4FAEBCDB & 0x000000FF = 0xDB
```

Similarly you can extract each individual bits by ANDing this byte with the particular     bit as one.

```
for 5th bit 
   0xDB & (1<<5)
for 6th bit
   0xDB & (1<<6)
```

If you wanted to extract the first byte(4F), you would do

```
 0x4FAEBCDB & (0xFF000000)
```

FF stands for (1111 1111) and the rest of the bits are 0. So doing the AND operation bitwise will return the byte at the position in which we specified 1s.

```
 Similarly (1<<5) generates 00010000.
```

Thus doing And operation with this will return the bit value at the particular position.

Comment: Hmm, guess you mean `(1<<5)`

Comment: Thank You, & small doubt , here how can we say DB is 4th byte ,and to get 4th byte u did AND with `0x000000FF` , How to know that value, what If i wana value of 5 or 6th byte.

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope it clarifies your question.

Comment: @rakeshbs Thank you , thank you very much, thats what I wanted.

Comment: `int x=0x4FAEBCDB;
         int bitmask = 0x000000FF;
         int val=x & bitmask;
         System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(val),16));` I did like this its not printing `DB`

Comment: it returns the base 10 value of the hexadecimel value DB. I used this code.
    int x=0x4FAEBCDB;
    int bitmask = 0x000000FF;
    int val=x & bitmask;
    System.out.println(val));

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the & operator for this.

For example, if your value is in variable int x,

```
(x & 0xFF000000) >> 24
```

will provide the 4th byte. In this, if you want to pick just the 5th and 6th bits, you can use

```
(x & 0x30000000) >> 28
```

Check out the link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html for more details.